# How to programmatically change text of SKLabelNode?

Tags: swift, xcode, sklabelnode

I added some SKLAbelNode into SKNode, which is placed inside SKScene

I need SKNode for grouping some nodes

I added name "altitude" to my SKLAbelNode

and put this code into SKScene class which was associated with my .sks file

```
var altitude:SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode()

override func sceneDidLoad()
{
     if let alti:SKLabelNode = self.childNode(withName: "altitude") as? SKLabelNode {
           altitude = alti
     }
}

...

override func didMove (...) {
     altitude.text = "000"
}
```

But always I get Fatal error

**UPD:** I solved this error, but got a question, why when I point a name of sknode even if it's inside in other node and try to get access to it i must point all tree something like

```
let altitude= (self.childNode(withName: "sknode") as! SKNode).childNode(withName: "altitude") as! SKLabelNode
altitude.text = "000"
```

Comment: What you are saying is like "I have a sister living on Main Street.  In order to send her a letter, the address must not just include the street name but also the names of the city and state where she lives."  You want the app to look for a node by stating its parent.  So you must state all tree branches.  Or you can start from self (SKScene) with `enumerateChildNodes` provided that the node has a unique name.

Comment: I though pointing the name of the node you make this name as global name and can get an access everywhere you wanna